# Routing Traffic through OpenVPN Client to get access to other devices on the local network of the client

Tags: ssh, vpn, proxy, port-forwarding

I have set up an OpenVPN server on a raspberry pi using PIVPN. This OpenVPN Server is located in network A. Using a dynamic DNS service I was able to successfully connect another raspberry pi at a different location (Network B) to the OpenVPN server at Network A.

Since the OpenVPN server saves a static virtual IP (10.8.0.0/24) for each connected client, I am able to route traffic over to the client using static a static IPv4-Routing Table on my router in network A. This way any network requests from network A to an ip address of the format 10.8.0.0/24 will first be send to the default gateway (my local router in network A) and there the routing table sends the request back to the openVPN server, that will use ip routing and its static IP-Address saved for each client to send the request all the way over to the client located in network B.

Very good. This way I am able to access web servers and applications running on the rasberry pi vpn client inside network B from within network A easily.

Now I would like to be able to access other network devices that are located within network B from within network A, without having each of the devices join the VPN as a client themselves (those devices can't even do that). Those devices each run their own web server. I want to get access to those web servers via HTTP(s) from within Network A. Furthermore I want to be able to connect via ssh to the other devices on network B.

I am a capable programmer, but do I lack expertise in networking. I think port forwarding may be a potential solution. If the client device joining the openVPN network was a router itself, it would be rather easy to configure this. But since the vpn client is a raspberry pi, I don't really know how to proceed. Another potential solution may be to set up a (reverse?) proxy on the raspberry pi client. Is there any piece of software, that I can configure on my raspberry pi client (network B) that will enable me to route traffic from network A all the way through to the other devices within network B? Or maybe I could try to transform my pi into a gateway somehow?

Please note that I do not want devices from network B (except maybe the raspberry pi client) to directly send packages to network A. I only want it the other way around. A site-to-site VPN is not really my goal. I have already done a similar thing using a [westermo-mrd-405](https://www.westermo.at/products/routers/wireless-routers/mrd-405) 4G router as vpn client without any problems using port forwarding (only traffic from VPN). This time I want to do it using a raspberry pi as a client.

Comment: show your configuration, logs and network layout, Thanks

Comment: a site-to-site vpn still is the best solution... you do not want devices on network B to access devices on network A? install a firewall (like iptables) and restrict the network flow like you want it to be...

Comment: Is there really no way to simply forward all traffic that arrives from network A on my raspberry pi (network B) to different hosts within network B (depending on request url) receive the response on the pi and send that back over to network A?  

If a potential soluton involves programming something myself thats fine. I just need to find the right concept so that I can go ahead and implement it.

Comment: Isn't a reverse proxy pretty much exactly what I would need for this? Why not? Thanks for your comments!

Comment: Hi Jakub. For HTTP traffic yes, you can use a reverse proxy on the OpenVPN client IP address in network A. But not for routing IP protocols. If you don't want to set up a site-to-site VPN, you would have to set up port forwardings for every host port in Network A, that should be reachable. This is possible with iptables.

Comment: Sounds very doable. I'll only have 4 clients that should be reachable and I don't even want any of the others to be reachable at all so I think this is the way to go.
Thanks !